# JSON.NET overwrites values of dictionary by populating

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, populate

I want to overwrite an existing object with some fields and dicitionary.

```
class MyInt {int value; int enchantment} // stat
enum MyEnum {FIRE, COLD, POISON}
class Creature {
    MyInt hp;
    MyInt mana;
    Dictionary<MyEnum, MyInt> resists;
}
...
Creature c = ...; // assigned elswhere (from Unity-Inspector)
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json_str, c);
```

After Populating object from JSon, fields hp and mana are correctly overwritten, but values of dictionary resists are recreated. Dictionary itself will be not recreated and has same hash_code after populating, what is correct. But the exemplars of `MyInt` will be recrated (with new HashCodes etc.).

My JSON Looks like that:

```
 {
   "hp": "3",
   "mana": "7",
   "resists": {
     "FIRE": "11",
     "COLD": "0",
     "POISON": "33"
   }
 }
```

I have found setting `ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse` but unfortunately it is same as `Auto` and does not help in this case.

Is any way to force JConvert overwrite the values of dictionary, without recreating new `MyInt` objects, like it works for fields hp/mana? Something like `JConvert.PopulateTransitive(...)`?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the problem, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Your code doesn't compile (fields are private) but when I fix that, `c.resists` is not replaced.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZ0UxH.  Also the JSON in your question can't be deserialized to your data model because `"3"` cannot be deserialized to `MyInt`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oF7gFj.

Comment: But maybe you're looking for `DictionaryMergeConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802477/3744182) to [Json.net - How to preserve dictionary value references when populating a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62783715/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc it is pseudocode to make example as little as possible. Yes correctly, resists itself will be not replaced. The problem that 3 values inside resists will be recreated. I want also to overwrite values of dictionary, without recreating them. (Background: theese objects are added to some collections that must be updated if objects are recreated)

Comment: Psuedocode can be unhelpful if we're trying to reproduce your problem.  For instance `DictionaryMergeConverter` might not work for you if you have some `TypeConverter` that converts `MyInt` from and to a string.  If you do, Json.NET will use it and you will be unable to populate existing instances.  But I can't test that without a real example.

Comment: @dbc Yes, exactly a have a TypeConverter for MyInt just to store values like "x / y". Otherwise DictionaryMergeConverter sounds right for this problem. So basically i need to overwrite a dictionary preserving values with same key. And values are my own class with it's own TypeConverter. Oh yes, i will update the question to make minimar reproducible example really work.

Comment: Json.NET is not going to be able to populate existing instances of `MyInt` when you have a `TypeConverter` assigned.  It will use the type converter and call `ConvertFrom()` and `ConvertTo()` to convert from and to the string representation -- but these methods have no way to populate an existing instance.  There's no `TypeConverter.PopulateFrom()` or `PopulateTo()`...

Comment: ... You will need to disable use of the type converter during serialization if you want to populate an existing instance.  To do that see [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Ah, i have looked question from the second comment: it is exactly the same. So my question is a dublicate. thank you.

Comment: Right, if you combine [Json.net - How to preserve dictionary value references when populating a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62783715/3744182) with [Newtonsoft.JSON cannot convert model with TypeConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325866/3744182) you may be all set.  Give it a try and see if it works.